# Unrecognized property 'consumerGroupId' in Kafka -> Lambda Integration using Serverless Framework

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

We are implementing a Self Managed Kafka -> Lambda implementation using the Serverless Framework. I was able to successfully deploy a lambda with Kafka as an event using the documentation [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml#msk:%7E:text=%2C%202%5D-,Kafka,-Kakfa%20events%3A), but the only property it is unable to recognize is **consumerGroupId**. I don't understand if I am missing an indentation or a type of variable all together, but I tried deploying many times with trial and error and none of these worked. Since this is an optional object, and the template is unable to recognize it, Lambda generated a UUID to assign to the consumergroupid which is failing the connection to Kafka. Any eyes on this would be much appreciated!! :)

Error:  Warning: Invalid configuration encountered
at 'functions.someLambda.events.0.kafka': unrecognized property 'consumerGroupId'
Here is the example code with permissions as well:

```
functions:
  someLambda:
    name: ${self:custom.config.namespace}-someLambda
    handler: src/someHandler.handler
    environment:
      NAMESPACE: ${self:custom.config.namespace}
    events:
      - kafka:
          # See main kafka documentation for various access configuration settings
          accessConfigurations:
            saslPlainAuth: some secret
            vpcSubnet:
              - subnet-a
            vpcSecurityGroup: sg-012345
          # An array of bootstrap server addresses
          bootstrapServers: #can add multiple if needed. 
            - someserver:9092
          topic: topicA
          batchSize: 100
          # Optional, can be set to LATEST, AT_TIMESTAMP or TRIM_HORIZON
          startingPosition: LATEST
          # Optional, specifies the consumer group ID to be used when consuming from Kafka. If not provided, a random UUID will be generated
          consumerGroupId: some.consumer.group
    iamPermissionsBoundary: !Sub some permission
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Action:
          - kms:Decrypt
          - kms:Encrypt
          - kms:ListAliases
          - kms:ListKeys
        Effect: Allow
        Resource:
          - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${aws:accountId}-${aws:region}-some-resource
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - xray:PutTelemetryRecords
          - xray:PutTraceSegments
        Resource:
          - '*'
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - cloudwatch:PutMetricData
          - logs:CreateLogGroup
          - logs:CreateLogStream
          - logs:PutLogEvents
          - logs:PutRetentionPolicy
        Resource:
          - '*'
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
          - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
          - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
          - ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups
          - ec2:DescribeSubnets
          - ec2:DescribeVpcs
        Resource: '*'
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
        Resource: '*'
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - kafka:DescribeCluster
          - kafka:DescribeClusterV2
          - kafka:GetBootstrapBrokers
          - kafka-cluster:Connect
          - kafka-cluster:DescribeTopic
          - kafka-cluster:ReadData
        Resource: '*'
    iamRoleStatementsName: ${self:service}-${aws:region}-role
```

I've tried to pass a string, destroy the stack and redeploy with each try, played around with the naming convention and indentation to just cross out the basics with the template, but nothing worked. I expect the consumer Id I am passing to be used instead of Lambda generating a UUID.

The consumer group I am passing is: some.consumer.group. That is the original format and not accessing some object value.

Comment: A UUID group id doesn't determine connectivity or not, unless you have ACLs configured on the cluster.

Comment: Also, you seem to be missing `SelfManagedKafkaEventSourceConfig`? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kafka.html#services-kafka-parms

Comment: Thanks for the response! 

We do have ACLs in this case which is why we may be seeing this issue. The reason I was able to deduct to this was because we had provided an existing consumer group ID from the AWS Console and it worked. If the UUID is used, we get the following error: 

- PROBLEM: Cluster failed to authorize Lambda.

And to answer the second part, since we are using Serverless Framework the following documentation was used: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml#msk:~:text=%2C%202%5D-,Kafka,-Kakfa%20events%3A

Comment: I forgot to add the link in the question. I will edit it quickly!

Comment: I have not used Serverless, but you may want to verify it supports connecting to any Kafka security protocol other than PLAINTEXT

Comment: Haha no worries. Yeah, it does have a few other protocols that can be used. In our case, it is setup with PLAINTEXT. I appreciate the help on this regardless. Always great to have different things to think about.

Comment: Please check your serverless version. make sure you have version above 3.23.0.

Comment: Upgrading the version from 3.22.0 to anything above worked!!